# Can not get Request data in custom service?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have custom service:

```
<?php
namespace App\Library\Services;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterCustomerService
{

    private $request;

    public function constructor(Request $request)
    {

        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function register($role)
    {

        dd($this->request);

     }

}
```

Why I can not get `dd($this->request);` when I do POST request:

```
$customer = $registerCustomerService->register('customer');
```

My service provider is:

```
class RegisterCustomerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Library\Services\RegisterCustomerService', function ($app) {
            return new RegisterCustomerService($request);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is a POST http request??
$customer = $registerCustomerService->register('customer');

Comment: How do you create the `$registerCustomerService` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind the instance in the container because Laravel can automatically resolve the namespace and the class dependencies if you resolve an object through the container.

You can the remove the binding from the service provider and use:

```php
$customer = app('App\\Library\\Services\\RegisterCustomerService')->register('customer');
```

In this way the container will resolve the Register customer service and will create that with all the needed dependencies (the request object in your example).